# Python collections.Counter efficiency

Tags: python, time-complexity, counter

I am using the following code to implement a function which finds all anagrams of string p in a string s.

```
class Solution(object):
    def findAnagrams(self, s, p):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type p: str
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        ans = list()
        pcnt = collections.Counter(p)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if collections.Counter(s[i:i+len(p)]) == pcnt:
                ans.append(i)
        return ans
```

when running on large length input string s, it gives me "time exceeds limit" error in the online code testing system. However the following code will work with no such issue:

```
class Solution(object):
    def findAnagrams(self, s, p):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type p: str
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        ls, lp = len(s), len(p)
        cp = collections.Counter(p)
        cs = collections.Counter()
        ans = []
        for i in range(ls):
            cs[s[i]] += 1
            if i >= lp:
                cs[s[i - lp]] -= 1
                if cs[s[i - lp]] == 0:
                    del cs[s[i - lp]]
            if cs == cp:
                ans.append(i - lp + 1)
        return ans
```

Can I know why? It seems both solution uses two Counters of maximum size of len(p)?

Comment: The first one uses far more than two Counters.  It creates a new counter on every loop iteration and then throws it away.  Not sure whether this is the cause of the difference in speed but it could be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To see why some code runs faster than other code, you should profile it. In Python, the easiest way to get started with profiling is to run:

```
python -m cProfile <script.py>
```

In my case, I wrote a simple script that calls either the slow solution or the fast solution:

```
# Pasted code from original question.
# Also renamed the slow version to `SlowSolution` and the fast version to `FastSolution`.
...

# solution = FastSolution()
solution = SlowSolution()

print(solution.findAnagrams('abcdefg' + 'a' * 10000, 'gfedcba' + 'a' * 10000))
```

Then I just ran the script using `SlowSolution` and `FastSolution`. Here's the output of my profiler results using `SlowSolution`:

```
$ python -m cProfile counter.py
[0]
         100204 function calls (100192 primitive calls) in 2.557 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    10008    0.015    0.000    2.538    0.000 __init__.py:516(__init__)
    10008    0.009    0.000    2.522    0.000 __init__.py:585(update)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _collections_abc.py:392(__subclasshook__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:16(__init__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:20(__enter__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:26(__exit__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:36(__init__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:52(_commit_removals)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:58(__iter__)
    20022    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 _weakrefset.py:70(__contains__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:81(add)
    10008    0.010    0.000    0.017    0.000 abc.py:178(__instancecheck__)
      7/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:194(__subclasscheck__)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.557    2.557 counter.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 counter.py:17(FastSolution)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 counter.py:3(SlowSolution)
        1    0.017    0.017    2.556    2.556 counter.py:4(findAnagrams)
    10008    2.490    0.000    2.490    0.000 {built-in method _collections._count_elements}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
        1    0.000    0.000    2.557    2.557 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
    10008    0.005    0.000    0.022    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
      8/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
    30024    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '__subclasses__' of 'type' objects}
       14    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'set' objects}
```

and `FastSolution`:

```
$ python -m cProfile counter.py
[0]
         146 function calls (134 primitive calls) in 0.005 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 __init__.py:516(__init__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:536(__missing__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 __init__.py:585(update)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _collections_abc.py:392(__subclasshook__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:16(__init__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:20(__enter__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:26(__exit__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:36(__init__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:52(_commit_removals)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:58(__iter__)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:70(__contains__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _weakrefset.py:81(add)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:178(__instancecheck__)
      7/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:194(__subclasscheck__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.005 counter.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 counter.py:17(FastSolution)
        1    0.004    0.004    0.005    0.005 counter.py:18(findAnagrams)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 counter.py:3(SlowSolution)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method _collections._count_elements}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.005 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
      8/2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.issubclass}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '__subclasses__' of 'type' objects}
       14    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'set' objects}
```

The output can be a little strange to read at first, but we're really interested in the `tottime` column. That tells us how much total time we spent inside of a particular function.

As you can see, the script spends almost all of its time inside of `{built-in method _collections._count_elements}`. That's an internal method used by a `Counter` which we can infer gets called every time you create a counter (like `collections.Counter(p)`).

To make the code faster, you should call `collections.Counter(...)` fewer times and/or with shorter strings. In the slow version, you're counting `len(p)` characters `len(s)` times. This has a runtime of `O(sp)` which is quadratic and explainswhy it's so slow on large inputs.

On the other hand, the faster solution counts each character of `s` exactly once which gives it a runtime of `O(s + p)`. This is much faster and will scale with much larger inputs.

For more info on profiling in Python, see [How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-script)

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, it is exactly what I need to learn!

Answer (score 2):

There is more overhead in creating, counting, and comparing `Counter` objects than for lists.  That is the essence of what you are seeing.  If you want a faster method still, you can accomplish the anagram finder by building the permutations of `p` as a tuple, then checking the slices of `s` against the tuple.

```
class Solution(object):
    def findAnagrams(self, s, p):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type p: str
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        ans = list()
        pcnt = collections.Counter(p)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if collections.Counter(s[i:i+len(p)]) == pcnt:
                ans.append(i)
        return ans

    def findAnagrams2(self, s, p):
        ls, lp = len(s), len(p)
        cp = collections.Counter(p)
        cs = collections.Counter()
        ans = []
        for i in range(ls):
            cs[s[i]] += 1
            if i >= lp:
                cs[s[i - lp]] -= 1
                if cs[s[i - lp]] == 0:
                    del cs[s[i - lp]]
            if cs == cp:
                ans.append(i - lp + 1)
        return ans

    def findAnagrams3(self, s, p):
        p_all = tuple(''.join(x) for x in permutations(p,len(p)))
        return [i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i:i+len(p)] in p_all]
```

Here is a short comparison of the 3 methods using `timeit` in IPython:

```
In [33]: %%timeit
    ...: sol.findAnagrams('hello world he said eh', 'he')
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop

In [34]: %%timeit
    ...: sol.findAnagrams2('hello world he said eh', 'he')
    ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop

In [35]: %%timeit
    ...: sol.findAnagrams3('hello world he said eh', 'he')
    ...:
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: thank you! this is interesting. One possible problem is that the permutations of p will take a lot of memory space when p is large?

Comment: how large of p are we talking about?