# Return len of similar values in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists which I want to return len() of similar values in a list.

```
A = [1,1,2,2]
B = [3,3,3,3,7,7,7]
```

In first list there are twice number 1 and 2, I want to use len of number values in the list, to see how many times number 1 repeats in first list. in that case will be 2 and 2 for number 2.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have tried for loop and len function, which does not work.

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried? Show the code, not vague references to concepts you used in the code.

Comment: I understand I would update my code

Comment: For `B`, would you want a result like `[4,3]`, since there are four 3s and three 7s?

Comment: Yes exactly,  I want to return from list `B` 4 for 3 and 3 for 7

Comment: The same as you mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick one single line solution that doesn't use collections counter.

```
A=[3,4,4,4,3,5,6,8,4,3]
duplicates=dict(set((x,A.count(x)) for x in filter(lambda rec : A.count(rec)>1,A)))
output:
{3: 3, 4: 4}
```

This solution doesn't account for "stretches" however

Comment: Your answer is short and simple :) Thanks

Comment: I just timed it and `collections.Counter` is over 100% faster @100,000 iterations each.

Comment: @nicholishen collections.counter has its time and place, and is clearly very effective for this situation. I edited post as it might have been misleading for this particular post. There are times when collections.counter is very slow and a creative solution could lead to better efficiency. [As seen in last answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485195/python-collections-counter-efficiency) I wanted to allude that there are times it is not the most effective solution, but might've overstepped the boundary of this post in doing so

Comment: @LarrBear Ironically, the reason your solution is slower than the `Counter` solution is the same reason that the `Counter` solution you linked to is slow.  Your solution is roughly quadratic, iterating over `A` multiple times for each element in `A`.  By contrast, building a `Counter` only iterates over `A` once.  That single iteration is more expensive than any one of the other iterations, but it's markedly more efficient than all of them taken together.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([1,1,2,2])
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2})
>>> Counter([3,3,3,3,7,7,7])
Counter({3: 4, 7: 3})
```

Comment: only if you do not care about "stretches":  [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2] will give only 1 number for 2s

Comment: Thanks.. Quick reply, but it gives back as dic. So I need  one more for-loop key and value to sort for exampel number 4 for 3 or 3 for 7.

Comment: No just access the dict using the key directly. `>>> number_of_threes = Counter([3,3,3,3,7,7,7])[3]`
... `4`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate over your numbers and count identical ones - or use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
def count_em(l):
    """Returns a list of lenghts of consecutive equal numbers as list. 
    Example: [1,2,3,4,4,4,3,3] ==> [1,1,1,3,2]"""
    if not isinstance(l,list):
        return None

    def count():
        """Counts equal elements, yields each count"""
        # set the first elem as current
        curr = [l[0]]

        # for the rest of elements
        for elem in l[1:]:
            if elem == curr[-1]:
                # append as long as the element is same as last one in curr 
                curr.append(elem)
            else:
                # yield the number
                yield len(curr)
                # reset curr to count the new ones
                curr = [elem]
        # yield last group
        yield len(curr)

    # get all yields and return them as list
    return list(count())


def using_groupby(l):
    """Uses itertools.groupby and a list comp to get the lenghts."""
    from itertools import groupby
    grp = groupby(l) # this groups by the elems themselfs
    # count the grouped items and return as list
    return [ sum(1 for _ in items) for g,items in grp]
```

Test:

```
A = [1,1,2,2]
B = [3,3,3,3,7,7,7]
C = [1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,6,6]

for e in [A,B,C]:
    print(count_em(e),  using_groupby(e))
```

Output:

```
# count_em     using_groupby    Input
[2, 2]         [2, 2]         # [1,1,2,2]
[4, 3]         [4, 3]         # [3,3,3,3,7,7,7]
[2, 3, 5, 2]   [2, 3, 5, 2]   # [1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,6,6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your professional answer. I appreciate and no doubt it would be useful.